# Maven integration for Eclipse cannot be installed

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I tried to install Maven Integration for Eclipse from Eclipse Market Place.

I had to cancel the installation in the mid because it took a long time.

I tried the installation after restarting the Eclipse, now I cannot find the "`Install`" button, instead there is an "`Update`" button which is disabled. (see the screen shot).

I tried un-installing and re-installing, but no success.

I am using Eclipse Indigo on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, m2e is enabled in Eclipse by default. No installation needed when it's already there.

Comment: How may I check that and make sure?

Comment: By looking at where you are at your screenshot and checking if it says to uninstall it instead of installing it. (In other words, your screenshot is proof) EDIT: You can try opening up maven projects too.

Comment: Well, then why I cannot un-install it?